# Record video and and download it with border in python using open cv and flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, opencv, flask

I'm attempting to record a video and download it with a border. I'm using the RGB color values 0, 0, 255 for the border. While I can easily download the recorded video, the border does not appear on it. When I click on the 'Start Recording' button, recording is initiated. Upon clicking the 'Stop Recording' button, a download button appears containing the link to download the video. However, the downloaded video lacks the border.

**APP.PY**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file
import cv2
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def add_border_to_video(video_path, output_path, border_thickness=20, border_color=(0, 0, 255)):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_path, fourcc, 20.0, (frame_width, frame_height))

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        # Add border to the frame
        bordered_frame = cv2.copyMakeBorder(frame, border_thickness, border_thickness, border_thickness, border_thickness, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=border_color)
        out.write(bordered_frame)

    cap.release()
    out.release()

@app.route('/record_video')
def record_video():
    # Record video with OpenCV
    # Make sure to save it to a file
    # For simplicity, let's assume the file is named 'recorded_video.mp4'
    recorded_video_path = 'recorded_video.mp4'

    # Add border to the recorded video
    bordered_video_path = 'output_with_border.mp4'
    add_border_to_video(recorded_video_path, bordered_video_path)

    return 'Video recorded and bordered successfully!'

@app.route('/download_video')
def download_video():
    # Serve the bordered video file for download
    bordered_video_path = 'output_with_border.mp4'
    return send_file(bordered_video_path, as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**INDEX.HTML** (HTML AND JS)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Record and Download Video</title>
    <style>
        /* CSS styles for the video container */
        #video-container {
            width: 640px;
            height: 480px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Record and Download Video</h1>

    <!-- Video container -->
    <div id="video-container">
        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
    </div>

    <!-- Buttons for recording and downloading -->
    <button id="startRecord">Start Recording</button>
    <button id="stopRecord" disabled>Stop Recording</button>
    <a id="downloadVideo" style="display: none;">Download Video</a>

    <!-- JavaScript code -->
    <script>
        const video = document.getElementById('video');
        const startRecordBtn = document.getElementById('startRecord');
        const stopRecordBtn = document.getElementById('stopRecord');
        const downloadVideoBtn = document.getElementById('downloadVideo');
        let mediaRecorder;
        let chunks = [];

        startRecordBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
            try {
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
                video.srcObject = stream;
                startRecordBtn.disabled = true;
                stopRecordBtn.disabled = false;
                downloadVideoBtn.style.display = 'none';
                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
                mediaRecorder.start();
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Error accessing camera:', err);
            }
        });

        stopRecordBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            startRecordBtn.disabled = false;
            stopRecordBtn.disabled = true;
        });

        function handleDataAvailable(event) {
            chunks.push(event.data);
            if (mediaRecorder.state === 'inactive') {
                const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'video/mp4' });
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                downloadVideoBtn.href = url;
                downloadVideoBtn.download = 'recorded_video.mp4';
                downloadVideoBtn.style.display = 'inline';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just for debugging purposes: have you tried to do the record part directly inside the donwload_video and test the download route?

Comment: yes, but still same issue, can you figure where im doing wrong

Comment: so, the bordered video display the right images but lakes of border?

Comment: yes i can download the video without border, there is no border applied.

Comment: is this a flask problem or an opencv problem, or matter of figuring out what code to write? [mre] please

Answer (score 0):

This aim to be a minimal example with focus on how and where *pre*- and *post*-process a video. No JavaScript is needed.

Due to the huge amount of online tutorial copying each other out I tried to give an "improved" version and also use *coroutines* to better separate the tasks of pre and post processing.

Once opening the root page, for ex `localhost:5000/`, the the camera will be turned on and *automatically* the video will be recorder. For stop the recording close the window (or partially reload the page).

```py
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, render_template_string, stream_with_context
import cv2


def coroutine(func):
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(cr)
        return cr
    return start


@stream_with_context
def stream_main(target, path_video):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Cannot open camera")
        # do routing stuffs
        #cap.release() # don't forget it:)
        return

    # type of the file extension that defines the output format
    frame_ext = '.jpg'
    if not frame_ext.startswith('.'):
        frame_ext = '.' + frame_ext

    # frame info
    frame_size = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

    # "initialize" coroutine
    target = target(path_video, *frame_size)

    # wrap binary image to html content
    def video_frame_content(frame:bytes) -> bytes:
        return b''.join((b'--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n', frame, b'\r\n'))

    while True:
        # capturing data (frame) from the camera
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print('Stream ended/interrupted?')
            break

        # save the frame
        target.send(frame)

        # pre-process the "live"-frame    <--------------
        # example: flip along the y-axis
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, flipCode=1)

        # prepare for streaming
        #
        # encodes an image into a memory buffer
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode(frame_ext, frame)
        if not ret:
            print('At Frame XY a problem occurred')

        yield video_frame_content(buffer.tobytes())
        
        # FPS
        time.sleep(0.04) # not mandatory

    cap.release()
    target.close()


@coroutine
def video_writer(dst_video, frame_width, frame_height):
    # post processing the frames
    
    # or declare them as parameters
    border_thickness = 20
    border_color = 0, 0, 255

    # video recording
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(
        dst_video, 
        cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'.lower()),
        10, 
        (frame_width+2*border_thickness,frame_height+2*border_thickness)
    )

    try:
        while True:
            # read the frame
            frame = (yield)

            # post-processing  <----------------
            # example: add border
            bordered_frame = cv2.copyMakeBorder(
                frame,
                border_thickness, border_thickness, border_thickness, border_thickness,
                cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
                value=border_color)

            out.write(bordered_frame)
    except Exception:
        # Done
        pass
    finally:
        out.release()


# routing
#########


# to add
path_video_border = # path of the new .mp4 file


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('Testing camera:<br><img src="{{ url_for("video_feed") }}">')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    # returns the streaming response
    return Response(stream_main(video_writer, path_video_border), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Notice further that in the OP there is a mistake when the writer is initialised: by adding a border to the frames their size change as well `out = cv2.VideoWriter( [...], (frame_width + 2*border_thickness, frame_height+2*border_thickness))`.

Comment: still no border

Comment: ok, I will investigate further. I found very strange that you were able to read the video with the wrong frame size

Comment: I fear is on JS/HTML-side... opencv is not processing that video (this explain why you didn't saw the mistake of the frames) and the downloaded video is called `recorded_video.webm` which has a different extension than the one in your code. Maybe you should add some Jinja code in index.html which process the output of the recording process

Comment: Jinja is installed together with Flask if I remember well, check it with `pip list`. It is a templating engine

Comment: Notice further that opencv support (multi) video capture with the following syntax `v2.VideoCapture(0)`. At the moment I can do much more than this

Comment: check [this](https://www.dynamsoft.com/codepool/web-camera-recorder-oepncv-flask.html) tutorial

Comment: the tutorial is about recording and download that video, no border is applied on it.
i have alredy done this

Answer (score 0):

Your code for adding a border doesn't take into account that the border makes the individual frame of the video larger. For this reason, the edited video cannot be played.

You also added the URL of the unedited video to the download button. The original is never sent to the server. Because of this, the code to add the border is not executed and the border is also not visible in the downloaded video.

The following example shows you how to record a video on the client side and send it to the server where it is edited. The edited video is then offered for download.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    abort, 
    render_template, 
    request, 
    send_from_directory
)
from mimetypes import guess_extension
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import cv2
import os 
import tempfile

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    UPLOAD_FOLDER=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads')
)
os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], exist_ok=True)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.post('/upload')
def upload():
    file = request.files.get('video')
    if file and file.filename != '':
        extname = guess_extension(file.mimetype)
        if not extname:
            abort(400)

        # Check the allowed file types here.

        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir=app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']) as tmpdirname:
            srcfile = secure_filename(f'{file.filename}{extname}')
            srcpath = os.path.join(tmpdirname, srcfile) 
            dstfile = f'output.mp4'
            dstpath = os.path.join(tmpdirname, dstfile)
            file.save(srcpath)

            convert(srcpath, dstpath) 

            return send_from_directory(tmpdirname, dstfile)

    abort(400)

def convert(src, dst, border=10, clr=(0,0,255)):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
    frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(
        dst, 
        cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 
        20.0, 
        (frame_width + 2*border, frame_height + 2*border)
    )

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frame = cv2.copyMakeBorder(
            frame, 
            border, border, border, border, 
            cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 
            value=clr
        )
        out.write(frame)

    out.release()
    cap.release()
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
    <style>
        a#dwl {
            display: None;
        }
        a#dwl.active {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video-container">
        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
    </div>

    <button id="start">Start Recording</button>
    <button id="stop" disabled>Stop Recording</button>
    <a id="dwl" href="#">Download</a>

    <script>
        (function() {
            const video = document.getElementById('video');
            const startBtn = document.getElementById('start');
            const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop');
            const dwlBtn = document.getElementById('dwl');

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                .then(stream => {
                    video.srcObject = stream;

                    let chunks = [];
                    let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

                    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
                        chunks.push(event.data);
                    };

                    mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
                        let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: mediaRecorder.mimeType });
                        chunks = [];

                        startBtn.disabled = false;
                        stopBtn.disabled = true;

                        const formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append('video', blob);

                        fetch('/upload', { method: 'post', body: formData })
                            .then(resp => resp.ok && resp.blob())
                            .then(blob => {
                                if (blob) {
                                    dwlBtn.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                    dwlBtn.download = 'output.mp4';
                                    dwlBtn.classList.add('active');
                                }
                            });
                    };

                    mediaRecorder.onstart = () => {
                        startBtn.disabled = true;
                        stopBtn.disabled = false;
                    };
            
                    stopBtn.addEventListener('click', () => mediaRecorder.stop());
                    startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => mediaRecorder.start());
                });

        })();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is some issue in your app.py file, cant run my project

Comment: @MEB The application ran without any problems for me. Which issue? Is there an error message?

Comment: @MEB I didn't add an `if __name__ == '__main__': app.run(debug=True)` line because I run the application via `flask --app app.py --debug run`. Add the line and you can run the app as usual.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. If you are satisfied with the result, please click on the check mark to accept the answer.